# Loading a URL in WKWebView looks way too zoomed in

Tags: ios, swift, url, wkwebview

I am using this code to load a URL in a WKWebView

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL)
webView.load(request)
```

When I load it the webview looks way to zoomed in. What could be the cause of this? I have looked through all of the settings and I don't see anything that clearly would solve this. I have tried different content modes with no effect.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a CSS issue which the web developer must resolve. This page has not been checked on mobile browsers thoroughly it seems. Does this URL load correctly in Safari?

Comment: @n00bProgrammer It loads fine in safari on the phone, though.

Comment: Does this page have javascript? I believe this is a preferences issue (refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252588/difference-between-wkwebview-and-safari))

Comment: Can you post more code? This seems like a problem with the configuration.

Comment: @MitulJindal That is literally all the code I am using to load the URL.

Comment: How are you instantiating the webview and how are you displaying it?

Comment: @MitulJindal I have the webview in a viewcontroller on the storyboard. Originally it is hidden, and when I click the link I send it to front and unhide.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer I tried following what you suggested with no luck.

Comment: There is WebKit view and a webview. I hope you are using the former.

Comment: @MitulJindal I am using the WKWebView NOT UIWebView

Comment: I have fixed the issue by creating a configuration and setting the ignoresViewportScaleLimits = false